# Post-Processing effects not visible with LWRP in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, post-processing, lwrp

I'm are running into an issue when setting up Post-Processing effects for the new Lightweight render pipeline.

Post-processing effects are visible in scene and Game view, but not through the camera when running the game.

- The project is using single pass rendering for VR
- We are using the LWRP 3.0.0 and the Post-Processing package 2.1.2 (both are up to date)
- It seems like the Post processing volume and layer settings are working fine, as the effects are visible in scene and game view

We tried :

- Tweaking the quality and graphics settings
- Creating a new camera and setting the post processing settings again
- Removing all additional cameras in the scene
- Setting the exiting UI Canvas in the scene to Screen Space (Camera) instead of Screen Space (Overlay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved : the issue was coming from other inactive Camera objects in the scene tagged as "MainCamera"